# How to retrieve the console logs of Apache IoTDB when deploying iotdb-session in springboot?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

After using maven to introduce the `iotdb-session` dependency in the springboot framework to run Apache IoTDB, the console log will turn gray after startup of IoTDB, and the previous logs (that can be normally printed) will not be printed. What is the reason and how can I change the framework setting to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the `iotdb-session` log framework in the `pom` file, and see if your log record returns to normal. The exclude commands you can execute in Apache IoTDB are as follows:

```
<exclusion>
<artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
<groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
<artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
</exclusion>
```